# WCF sending int[] from client to server

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I experience this issue:

I have a WCF service, that exposes this operation contract:

```
[OperationContract]
void Index(int[] song, string fileName);
```

On my client, I have:

```
AudioDetectionServiceReference.AudioDetectionServiceClient client = new AudioDetectionServiceReference.AudioDetectionServiceClient();
client.Index(max.ToArray(), mp3Files[i]);
```

Where max is an array of 2000 int values, and mp3Files[i] is a string of 200 chars.

Web.config has this:

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And app.config has:

```
    <configuration>
        <system.serviceModel>

            <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAudioDetectionService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                        <security mode="None">
                            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                                realm="" />
                            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                        </security>
                    </binding>
                </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:15863/AudioDetectionService.svc"
                    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAudioDetectionService"
                    contract="AudioDetectionServiceReference.IAudioDetectionService"
                    name="BasicHttpBinding_IAudioDetectionService" />
            </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
    <startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Now comes the tricky part:

When you right click on service reference, go to configure service reference, there is an option called Collection type. If I set the collection type to "Syste.Array" I get the error

```
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.
```

With the stack trace:

```
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at SqlTest.AudioDetectionServiceReference.IAudioDetectionService.Index(Int32[] song, String fileName)
       at SqlTest.AudioDetectionServiceReference.AudioDetectionServiceClient.Index(Int32[] song, String fileName) in blablabla\Service References\AudioDetectionServiceReference\Reference.cs:line 53
       at SqlTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in blablabla\Program.cs:line 46
```

When I change it to "System.Collection.Generic.List", the error magically disappears.

My question is : **WHY?**

Second question:

**Why** does this work?

```
client.Index(max.Take(100).ToArray(), mp3Files[i]);
```

using the same context (app.config, web.config, and the same code as above, with the System.Array selected).

Thanks,
Andrei Neagu

PS: I post this because I spent 2 days on trying to change settings for bindings, change the message size, change values from readerQuotas and other stuff, when all I had to do what this stupid selection. So I am quite pissed and I wanna at least learn something from this.

Comment: Try looking at the request which is sent to the server in both cases (array and list) in Fiddler, to see if there is a difference between those.

Comment: The best trouble shooting is to turn on WCF tracing on the service. You'll get to see the real exception that thrown instead of "bad request". http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx. Its a little time consuming, but worth it.

Comment: Also, try to set `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>` to `true`, which might give you a better error response

Comment: Tried to use Fiddler, but the client is an Console application for now, and it doesn't show any info. Browser activity is shown.

Comment: Even if I set these values for debug mode, the error is still 400. No other info is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging, this is what I changed:

app.config

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAudioDetectionService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="655360" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="320" maxStringContentLength="81920" maxArrayLength="163840"
                maxBytesPerRead="40960" maxNameTableCharCount="163840" />
            <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                    realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:15863/AudioDetectionService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAudioDetectionService"
        contract="AudioDetectionServiceReference.IAudioDetectionService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IAudioDetectionService" />
</client>
```

and for the server, look at the fact that there is no name for the basicHttpBinding section. I think that if this section has a name, the default service generated by WCF will ignore it.

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="655360" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="320" maxStringContentLength="81920" maxArrayLength="163840"
          maxBytesPerRead="40960" maxNameTableCharCount="163840" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And for the other values, I added an 0 at the end (multiplied by 10). Increasing them I think will let you transfer event more. But the most important, the basicHttpBinding has no name. If it had a name, I think it was ignored.

I will not set this as answered, because the question was why System.Array throws exception and System.Generic.List does not.