# System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException error while trying to pass an IEnumerable object

Tags: c#, wcf

I am making a small WCF client server application where users can send messages and check their inbox. I have a custom `Message` class which has the fields: `message_to`, `message_from`, `message_text`, `message_time`.

Since I would need to display the messages on the client UI, I am returning an IEnumerable `Messages` object to the client. I designated the Message class as a `DataContract` and the fields `message_from`, `message_text`, `message_time` as a `DataMember`.

When trying to access the messages from the client, I get the following error:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:9002/vService/CheckService.
```

[Here is the paste of the complete exception.](http://pastebin.com/zFR82CNW)

The service proxy on the client side is

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICheckService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<Message> CheckInbox(string user);
```

I have enabled logging and tracing, but nothing turns up in the logs. Here is the [web.config](http://pastebin.com/msw00nx3)

Message class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Message
{
    public int Message_Id;
    [DataMember]        
    public string Message_from;
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime Message_time;
    public string Message_to;
    [DataMember]
    public string Message_text;

    public Message()
    {
    }
}
```

The generated proxy class, [reference.cs](http://pastebin.com/cj1Wrsq3)

A lot of people on SO have received this error and unfortunately none of their solutions worked for me. I feel I am still missing something.

Comment: have you tried this? I laso had some problems with wcf recently, and got fixed by changing the collection type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710361/wcf-sending-int-from-client-to-server/10721983#10721983

Comment: It took me a while to figure out where this option was in SharpDevelop. I changed the CollectionType to `System.Collections.Generic.List`, but I get the same error.

Comment: I had even tried adding a zero to each numeric value like you did, but still no luck.